# Why does courage take du, and peur does not take de la with avoir?

Tags: articles

The translation of "You have courage" is "Tu as du courage.", whereas the translation of "You have fear" is "Tu as peur."
How do we decide when to use the partitive articles in these kind of situations?

Comment: Courage is the norm. There's a finite number of fixed expressions without an article that you just have to memorize: faim, soif, chaud, froid, sommeil, besoin, honte, envie, hâte, raison, tort, peur. I guess marre too. Those are the most common -- maybe there are others or archaic ones. Of course, as always happens, exceptions are few in number but dominate in usage...

Comment: *Tu as de la peur* is not common but would be acceptable, *tu as courage* would not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

- **peur** is an emotion. One feels it.
- **courage** is a manifest of character or simply a personality. One has or gets it

While feeling `peur`, we can manifest courage to face the situation. Or we manifest cerenity to think better about the situation.

I come back to your question.
To have courage is not feeling good or bad. It is why we own the courage. In opposite to be scared is not having something to take any action. We don't own fear.

To conclude

- Tu as **du courage**
- Tu as **de la peur** or Tu as **peur**

The both are good.

- Tu as **de la peur** en toi
- Tu as **du courage** en toi

[Luke Sawczak](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51741/why-does-courage-take-du-and-peur-does-not-take-de-la-with-avoir#comment107285_51741) said in his comment: it became a norm sometime in the time. In my opinion it is more like a feeling.

And [Jiliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51741/why-does-courage-take-du-and-peur-does-not-take-de-la-with-avoir#comment107295_51741) Said `tu as peur` is ok but as courage is a manifest `tu as courage` is bad.

Il hope you got your answer